# Vim's mksession doesn't save window maximized state

Tags: windows, vim

I use **Vim**'s [Obsession plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-obsession), but every time I `:source` the session file, the window doesn't remember it was maximized (and it was when I closed it). It does remember everything else.

My session options are:

`sessionoptions=blank,buffers,curdir,folds,help,options,tabpages,winsize,terminal,resize,winpos`

I use **gVim 8.1** on Windows 10 with the following plugins:

```
  Plug 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe', { 'do': function('BuildYCM') }
  Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
  Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
  Plug 'hzchirs/vim-material'
  Plug 'kristijanhusak/vim-hybrid-material'
  Plug 'https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround.git'
  Plug 'https://github.com/tpope/vim-obsession.git'
  Plug 'https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired.git'
  Plug 'https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat.git'
  Plug 'https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors.git'
  Plug 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'
  Plug 'https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim.git'
  Plug 'scrooloose/nerdcommenter'
  Plug 'https://github.com/octol/vim-cpp-enhanced-highlight.git'
  Plug 'luochen1990/rainbow'
  Plug 'https://github.com/tomtom/tlib_vim.git'
  Plug 'https://github.com/MarcWeber/vim-addon-mw-utils.git'
  Plug 'https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate.git'
  Plug 'https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets.git'
```

I tried removing `set lines` and `au GUIEnter * winpos` from my _vimrc file just to try something, but the problem persists.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Just change your shell link properties to start always maximized.

Comment: Sure, but even if I start maximized by default, window gets un-maximized when I source the session :(

Comment: Remove `winpos` from `sessionoptions`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SessionLoadPost` autocmd to do additional work after you load a session.

```
augroup more_lines
    autocmd!
    autocmd SessionLoadPost * set lines=999
augroup END
```

For more help see:

```
:h 'lines'
:h SessionLoadPost
```

Comment: Ok, that did the trick, except I used `autocmd SessionLoadPost * simalt ~x` instead. Thanks!